# IntelliJ Database: How to export only changed table rows to an update SQL script?

Tags: sql, database, intellij-idea, export

How can one create an update sql script by using intellijs database tool?

I have a database table and I want to edit some columns by clicking in the row and edit them.
Once I have edited all that is necessary, I need a SQL that updates the table.

Is there an export feature that creates such a sql script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have made modification in the data cells which are supposed to highlight after modification, you can `right click` then click `submit` or press <kbd>Ctrl+Enter</kbd> to run the script which you can copy from the console and save in external file.

> Make sure to do that in local database only and not make unexpected changes in production.